# JSON request not responded

Tags: android, json, webserver

I have a webservice which returns json files. If I call this url (http://192.168.178.67:8080/simplestock/webapi/swipeService/swipes/Aktien) on my smartphone browser, I will get a json array back.

Now I've tried to get this json in my android project with this code:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d("Success", "onResponse is Called");

            try {
                Log.d("Get Object: ", response.getJSONArray(1).toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Failure", "JSON Error");
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("JSON", "Error");
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the respond isn't called and I don't get any error message. I've added the internet permission in the manifest. I test on my smartphone, which is in the same network than the localhost. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Does the device connected with the same `network`?  Have you checked response with rest client (Ex Postman )?

Comment: yes the device is connected with the same network. no I didn't whats this

Comment: now I've tested with chrome rest client and this works too

Comment: You code example doesn't show it, but did you add `jsonObjectRequest.add(jsonArrayRequest);``?

Comment: @barns no i didn't

Answer (score 0):

In what ever method you are calling your code you need to add the request to the queue: `jsonObjectRequest.add(jsonArrayRequest);`

Like this:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d("Success", "onResponse is Called");
        try {
            Log.d("Get Object: ", response.getJSONArray(1).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Failure", "JSON Error");
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.d("JSON", "Error");
}
});

jsonObjectRequest.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```